# How to convert unordered list into nicely styled <select> dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

How do I convert an unordered list in this format

```
<ul class="selectdropdown">
    <li><a href="one.html" target="_blank">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="two.html" target="_blank">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="three.html" target="_blank">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="four.html" target="_blank">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="five.html" target="_blank">five</a></li>
    <li><a href="six.html" target="_blank">six</a></li>
    <li><a href="seven.html" target="_blank">seven</a></li>
</ul>
```

into a dropdown in this format

```
<select>
    <option value="one.html" target="_blank">one</option>
    <option value="two.html" target="_blank">two</option>
    <option value="three.html" target="_blank">three</option>
    <option value="four.html" target="_blank">four</option>
    <option value="five.html" target="_blank">five</option>
    <option value="six.html" target="_blank">six</option>
    <option value="seven.html" target="_blank">seven</option>
</select>
```

using jQuery?

*Edit:* When selecting an entry from the select/dropdown the link should open in a new window or tab automatically. I also want to able to style it like: http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

Comment: @Dominic Rodger - The code i given is just for example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('ul.selectdropdown').each(function() {
    var select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());
    $('>li a', this).each(function() {
        var a = $(this).click(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('target')==='_blank') {
                window.open(this.href);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = this.href;
            }
        }),
        option = $(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html()).click(function() {
            a.click();
        });
    });
});
```

**In reply to your last comment**, I modified it a little bit but haven't tested it. Let me know.

```
$('ul.selectdropdown').each(function() {
    var list = $(this), select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());

    $('>li a', this).each(function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('target'),
        option = $(document.createElement('option'))
            .appendTo(select)
            .val(this.href)
            .html($(this).html())
            .click(function(){
                if(target==='_blank') {
                    window.open($(this).val());
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = $(this).val();
                }
            });
    });
    list.remove();
});
```

Comment: code working to make dropdown but links not opening in new window

Comment: link opening in same tab in firefox

Comment: It should only open a new window with a _blank target on the link. Have you dropped a console.log into the if statement to see if it's trying to open in a new window?

Comment: yes your code was right. it was my mistake i had not added target=_blank . now it working fine u can see here http://jsbin.com/agane thanks for this.

Comment: but now the problem is unordered still showing in source code

Comment: Cool it's perfect now. now i just want to give cool look to this <select> like this pluging does http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

Comment: hi guys, i have tried your example at http://jsbin.com/etoyu it is working fine on FF but doesn't on chrome and safari... any idea??

Comment: use change instead of click - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340690/javascript-onclick-alert-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: Use change(), but on the select element, not the option: `select.change(function() {
      window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });` <-----this should get the above code to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 21):

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.selectdropdown').each(function() {
        var $select = $('<select />');

        $(this).find('a').each(function() {
            var $option = $('<option />');
            $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
            $select.append($option);
        });

        $(this).replaceWith($select);
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

As with any jQuery code you want to run on page load, you have to wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block, or inside it's shorter version `$(function() { ... });`. I updated the function to show this.

**EDIT**

There *was* a bug in my code also, tried to take href from the li element.

Comment: You are trying to execute the script inside <style> tags, change those to <script>. I also updated my function, there was a small mistake.

Comment: oh , my mistake , solved now now i added ur latest code it's working now http://jsbin.com/igano but on select a item from dropdown i wanted to open link in new window

Comment: @Jitendra, opening link on change and styling the select is out of the scope for this question, Google has a lot of resources for both of those. If the code is working, lets just close this one.

Comment: Yes code is working and great thanks for it. I closed the question but if u can give the way to open links in new window then it would be better

Comment: I found a another js solution for same http://www.onlinetools.org/tests/enhancedropdown.html and in this link opens in new window but the problem is it's not jquery based

Comment: First you need to bind the created select element to a change event, and in that, get the value and redirect the browser. If you have problems with that, post a new question but try to do it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is working also in IE and working with selected item (in anchor tag).

```
$('ul.selectdropdown').each(function(){
var list=$(this),
    select=$(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide()).change(function(){
  window.location.href=$(this).val();
});
$('>li a', this).each(function(){
  var option=$(document.createElement('option'))
   .appendTo(select)
   .val(this.href)
   .html($(this).html());
  if($(this).attr('class') === 'selected'){
    option.attr('selected','selected');
  }
});
list.remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for posting the codes. My scenario is similar but my situation is for Responsiveness that for x-size it would switch to a dropdown list, then if not x-size,  using [csswatch](https://github.com/leifcr/jquery-csswatch/) to check for the "display" properties of an element that has certain amount of width set to it (eg: 740px). Thought I share this solution for anyone who is interested. This is what I have combined with Tatu' codes. Instead of replacing the html, I created then hide the new html then only add them when necessary:

```
var $list = $('ul.list');
(listFunc = function(display){

    //Less than x-size turns it into a dropdown list
    if(display == 'block'){
        $list.hide();
        if($('.sels').length){
            $('.sels').show();
        } else {
            var $select = $('<select class="sels" />');

            $list.find('a').each(function() {
                var $option = $('<option />');
                $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
                $select.append($option);
            });

            $select.insertAfter($list);

            $('.sels').on('change', function(){
                window.location = this.value;
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('.sels').hide();
        $list.show();
    }
})(element.css('display'));
element.csswatch({
    props: 'display'
}).on('css-change', function (event, change) {
    return listFunc(change.display);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created a solution where the ul transformed, mimics nearly completely the select.

It has in adition a search for the options of the select and supports the active state. Just add a class with name active and that option will be selected.

It handles the keyboard navigation.

Take a look at the code here: [GitHub Code](https://github.com/quanton81/quanton-ul-to-select)

And a live example here: [Code Example](http://www.ciaomondo.it/blog/convertire-ul-in-select-con-search.php)

The unordered list must be in the form:

```
<ul id="...">
  <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="...">...</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

To convert the ul to select just call:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  ulToSelect($("ul#id"), 767);
});
```

Where #id is an id for the unordered list and 767 is the minimum width of the window for the convertion to take place. This is very useful if you want the convertion to take place only for mobile or tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I found this gorgeous CodePen from @nuckecy for anyone interested:

https://codepen.io/nuckecy/pen/ErPqQm

```
$(".select").click(function() {
  var is_open = $(this).hasClass("open");
  if (is_open) {
    $(this).removeClass("open");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("open");
  }
});

$(".select li").click(function() {

  var selected_value = $(this).html();
  var first_li = $(".select li:first-child").html();

  $(".select li:first-child").html(selected_value);
  $(this).html(first_li);

});

$(document).mouseup(function(event) {

  var target = event.target;
  var select = $(".select");

  if (!select.is(target) && select.has(target).length === 0) {
    select.removeClass("open");
  }

});
```

His default CSS rules:

```
.select li {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.select li:first-child {
  display: block;
  border-top: 0px;
}

.select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.select li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.select li:first-child:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.select.open li {
  display: block;
}

.select span:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  content: "\2193";
}

.select.open span:before {
  content: "\2191";
}
```