# What is the best way to make jump menu (HTML select dropdown)?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

Every `<option>` in an HTML `<select>` will have external URL and should open in new a window. If it's possible to make in CSS and HTML only then good, if not possible without JavaScript then it should be unobtrusive.

Comment: "To not". Seriously, jump menus are a horrible bit of UI design (as are new windows that are not user triggered)

Answer (score 17):

The “jump menu” is a discredited navigational device from many years ago that should not be brought back.

Auto-navigate-on-change `<select>` menus are unsuitable for navigation because:

1. keyboard users will be firing a change event every time they move the selection, making it impossible for them to use the control;
2. non-JavaScript agents (including search engines) won't be able to see or follow the links;
3. form values are retained over page back/forward navigations, making the select show the wrong value after a navigation, making it impossible to select the same option again;
4. users can't use their browser's normal navigational tools like middle-click, ‘open in new tab’ or ‘bookmark link’.

Therefore the ‘best’ way to make a jump menu is not to. If you want something that behaves similarly but doesn't have these disadvantages, go for a `<div>` that's hidden and re-popped-up by JavaScript, containing plain `<a>` links pointed at the pages they go to. You can style it to look like a dropdown if you really want, and you can make them open new windows when left-clicked if you must (I wish you wouldn't, though).

Comment: but use of scripted <div> is schematically correct? and if we will use <div> then what will happen if css and js is disabled

Comment: If CSS is disabled you get a simple list of links, which is about the best you can hope for. To make it still usable without JS, you have the div visible in the normal page, then use script to hide it until it's toggled open.

Comment: ok then i think this will be a good option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery

Comment: I agree with the general principle, but: “Keyboard users will be firing a change event every time they move the selection, making it impossible for them to use the control.” Is that true? I thought the `onchange` event only fired once you’d actually chosen an option in a `select` field.

Comment: It's browser-dependent. Currently IE and Opera fire `onchange` on every keyboard up/down, whilst Firefox and Webkit delay the `onchange` until `onblur`. (Which isn't great either: you choose a page, then nothing happens until you happen to click or tab to somewhere else, causing the field to unfocus.)

Comment: i realized if <select> is not good then why we need to make it from <div> and <a> we can make it from regular <ul> <li> <a>

Answer (score 3):

You can't open links from `<select>` elements without Javascript. The way to open a new Window with Javascript is like this:

```
window.open("http://example.com");
```

To attach to the `<select>` element, try this:

```
$('#selectId').change( function() {
    window.open( $(this).val() );
}
```

Assuming the URL is set in the `value` attribute of each `<option>` element.