# Onchange open URL via select - jQuery

Tags: jquery, onchange

What would be the best way to attach an event so on change of a select option a URL. Store the href in an attr and grab it on change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to make jump menu (HTML select dropdown)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138998/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-jump-menu-html-select-dropdown)

Answer (score 225, accepted):

It is pretty simple, let's see a working example:

```
<select id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</option>
  <option value="https://www.gurustop.net">GuruStop.NET</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

```js
$(function() {
  // bind change event to select
  $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function() {
    var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
    if (url) { // require a URL
      window.location = url; // redirect
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</option>
  <option value="https://www.gurustop.net">GuruStop.NET</option>
</select>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"
        ></script>
```

.

### Remarks:

- The question **specifies jQuery already**. So, I'm keeping other alternatives out of this.
- In older versions of jQuery (< 1.7), you may want to replace `on` with `bind`.
- This is extracted from JavaScript tips in [Meligy’s Web Developers Newsletter](https://www.gurustop.net/).

.

Comment: Modern jQuery 1.7+ versions would use on() instead of bind().

`$('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {`

Comment: I already had a note about this long time ago (See revisions of the answer), but removed it since `bind` is not depreciated. However, since I got this comment almost a day after I removed it, I put it back now.

Comment: thanks, works perfect. Is there a way to make the select box show the selected option after the change event has fired?

Comment: I think if you don't `return false` it will keep the selected option there.

Comment: This works. Just wanted to add that I first tried it without a slash / at the end of the URL and it did not work. It apparently needs that forward slash.

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me http://embed.plnkr.co/XDkc4h5M4nVJS22RwK7u/ -- I changed the StackOverflow link because in this sample the page opens in an iframe, and StackOverflow doesn't like to opened in a frame for some security reason!

Comment: But this opens a new tab? or replaced the current window?

Answer (score 200):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="">Pick one:</option>
    <option value="/foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="/bar">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hi @Mark, how to make the option is selected, when it is redirected,

Comment: @jafar-pinjar I'm not sure what you're asking. Probably best to create a new question.

Comment: @MarkEirich, here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037550/redirect-issue-in-select-element

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, but there's to much coding going on here ...

I'll give the simplest one to you for free. I invented it back in 2005, although the javascript source now says it was their staff who came up with it - more than a year later!

Anyway, here it is, no javascript !!!

```
<!-- Paste this code into the BODY section of your HTML document  -->
<select size="1" name="jumpit" onchange="document.location.href=this.value"> 
<option selected value="">Make a Selection</option>
<option value="http://www.javascriptsource.com/">The JavaScript Source</option>
<option value="http://www.javascript.com">JavaScript.com</option>
<option value="http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=3">JavaScript Forums</option>
<option value="http://www.scriptsearch.com/">Script Search</option>
<option value="http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/diaries/">The JavaScript Diaries</option>
</select>
```

Just type in any URL you like, or a relative URL (to the pages location on server), it will always work.

Comment: 1. There is nothing 'invented' about this. 2. I would be shocked if you wanted money for this. 3. I doubt anyone else claims to have "come up with it".

Comment: "javascript source now says it was their staff who came up with it"
"Anayways, here it is, no javascript !!!"

i'm kinda confused now

Comment: hats off to your confidence. "I'll give the simplest one to you for free", aww!...

Comment: "no javascript" - what do you think `document.location.href=this.value` is?

Answer (score 10):

You can use this simple code snippet using jQuery to redirect from a drop down menu.

```
<select id="dynamic-select">
    <option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</option>
    <option value="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#dynamic-select').bind('change', function () { // bind change event to select
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
        if (url != '') { // require a URL
            window.location = url; // redirect
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can replace `$(this).val()` with `this.value` and `url != ''` with `url !== ''`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how i'd do it

```
<select id="urlSelect" onchange="window.location = jQuery('#urlSelect option:selected').val();">
 <option value="http://www.yadayadayada.com">Great Site</option>
 <option value="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Better Site</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can do it much easier wihout jQuery
onchange="window.location = this.value;"

Answer (score 5):

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RX8BC/7/)

```
$('#userNav').change(function() {
window.location = $(':selected',this).attr('href')
});




<select id="userNav">
<option></option>
<option href="http://google.com">Goolge</option>
<option href="http://duckduckgo.com">Go Go duck</option>
</select>
```

This works for the href in an option that is selected

Answer (score 5):

I believe the simplest way to redefine a location inside select tab is as follows:

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
     <option value="https://www.google.com/">Home</option>
     <option value="https://www.bing.com">Contact</option>
     <option value="mypets.php">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Super easy way is as following. No need to create a function.

```
<select onchange="window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="">Switch Language</option>
    <option value="{{ url('/en') }}">English</option>
    <option value="{{ url('/ps') }}">پښتو</option>
    <option value="{{ url('/fa') }}">دری</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change_url(val) {
            window.location=val;
        }
    </script>            
    <select style="width:130px;" onchange="change_url(this.value);">
            <option value="http://www.url1.com">Option 1</option>
            <option value="http://www.url2.com">Option 2</option>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the url to put it on option's value, i'll give u example :

```
<select class="abc">
    <option value="0" href="hello">Hell</option>
    <option value="1" href="dello">Dell</option>
    <option value="2" href="cello">Cell</option>
</select>

    $("select").bind('change',function(){
        alert($(':selected',this).attr('href'));
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="xx" class="xxx" onchange="_name(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel'))">
  <option value="x" rel="xy">aa</option>
  <option value="xxx" rel="xyy">bb</option>
</select>


//for javascript
function _name(value,rel) {
alert(value+"-"+rel);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code its working perfect**

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#submit").hide();

    $("#page-changer select").change(function() {
        window.location = $("#page-changer select option:selected").val();
    })

});
</script>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['nav'])) {
         header("Location: $_POST[nav]");
    }
?>
<form id="page-changer" action="" method="post">
    <select name="nav">
        <option value="">Go to page...</option>
        <option value="http://css-tricks.com/">CSS-Tricks</option>
        <option value="http://digwp.com/">Digging Into WordPress</option>
        <option value="http://quotesondesign.com/">Quotes on Design</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible for this to work once the users clicks the 'Go' input button?

Answer (score 1):

```
**redirect on change option with jquery** 

 <select id="selectnav1" class="selectnav">
            <option value="#">Menu </option>
            <option value="   https://www.google.com">
            Google
            </option>
            <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/">
              stackoverflow
            </option>

         </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {

        $('#selectnav1').change( function() {
      location.href = $(this).val();
   });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code its working Firefox, Chrome, IE

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="" selected>---Select---</option>
<option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
<option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
<option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
<option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
```