# Convert a hierarchical unordered list to a select list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to achieve something similar like the question [How to convert unordered list into nicely styled  dropdown using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery), but with a hierarchical ul list. I want to convert this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/about/staff">Staff</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current-page"><a href="/about/staff/john-doe">John Doe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about/staff/jane-doe">Jane Doe</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/products/games">Games</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/products/games/xbox">XBOX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products/games/ps3">PlayStation 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products/games/ipad">iPad</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products/games/iphone">iPhone</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/products/hardware">Hardware</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/products/hardware/controllers">Controllers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products/hardware/memory">Memory units</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/products/upcoming">Upcoming</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

To this:

```
<select>
    <option value="/">Home</option>
    <option value="/about">About us</option>
    <option value="/about/staff">- Staff</option>
    <option value="/about/staff/john-doe" selected>-- John Doe</option>
    <option value="/about/staff/jane-doe">-- Jane Doe</option>
    <option value="/products">Products</option>
    <option value="/products/games">- Games</option>
    <option value="/products/games/xbox">-- XBOX</option>
    <option value="/products/games/ps3">-- PlayStation 3</option>
    <option value="/products/games/ipad">-- iPad</option>
    <option value="/products/games/iphone">-- iPhone</option>
    <option value="/products/hardware">- Hardware</option>
    <option value="/products/hardware/controllers">-- Controllers</option>
    <option value="/products/hardware/memory">-- Memory</option>
    <option value="/products/upcoming">- Upcoming</option>
    <option value="/contact">Contact us</option>
</select>
```

The class "current-page" on the li should mark the corresponding option in the select as `selected`. A jQuery as well as vanilla JavaScript would do.

Comment: To clarify: The ul list can have more than three levels in its hierarchy so there shouldn't be any limit to that.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? please post your code sample.

Comment: Have you tried starting with the script from the question you linked with a slightly different selector? If you make your selector select all li elements that are descendants of your root ul then put them in a list then that should do the trick mostly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some jQuery code doing what you want. As I don't know where you want the `<select>` appended, I'm just appending it directly to `<body>`. There's also an issue of the `$('li')` selector being too greedy (it will select all `<li>` elements in the document), but it's easy to fix given the knowledge about the parent elements of the `<ul>` element you've posted.

```
(function($) { $(function() {
    var $select = $('<select>')
        .appendTo('body');

    $('li').each(function() {
        var $li    = $(this),
            $a     = $li.find('> a'),
            $p     = $li.parents('li'),
            prefix = new Array($p.length + 1).join('-');

        var $option = $('<option>')
            .text(prefix + ' ' + $a.text())
            .val($a.attr('href'))                       
            .appendTo($select);

        if ($li.hasClass('current-page')) {
            $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });
});})(jQuery);
```

I would also consider using [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/optgroup.html) instead of the `-` prefix as a way of indicating the hierarchy level.

Comment: wow, this is brilliant. I also added the snippet from here to go to the URL on change: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5150486/819276  Thanks!