# html form select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This is kinda annoying, but even though I have worked with html/css and tiny bit of jquery I haven't yet learned much about forms etc.

I have a problem and I cant google the answer, but im sure some of you hardcore devs can tell me this quick!?

I need to make a form that could look like this:

**HTML**;

```
<form class="slct-form">
    <select>
        <option value="choose">Choose</option>
        <option value="100.000">100.000</option>
        <option value="150.000">150.000</option>
        <option value="200.000">200.000</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I need that when I choose one of the elements in my dropdown form it should go to another url... Is this not possible? AND preferable without jquery!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150363/onchange-open-url-via-select-jquery for a jquery version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function donav(dd)
        {
            var navUrl = "";
            switch(dd.selectedIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    navUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    navUrl = "http://www.bing.com";
                    break;
         }
         document.location.href = navUrl;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form class="slct-form">
    <select onchange="donav(this)">
        <option value="choose">Choose</option>
        <option value="100.000">100.000</option>
        <option value="150.000">150.000</option>
        <option value="200.000">200.000</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add an `id` to your `select`, you can access it via plain javascript like this:

```
var selectmenu = document.getElementById("selectMenu");
selectmenu.onchange = function() {
    var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    if (selectedOption.value != "choose")
        window.location.assign = "/page.php?selectvalue=" + selectedOption.value;
}
```

Comment: How would this work then? Im sorry, im not so good with java script... If i have 3 different values that each should go to 3 different websites. My site is pure html - not .php

Comment: @user1719764 I just added the link as an example, you would just need to replace the part in quotes (`"page.php?selectvalue="`) with the URL you require.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you corretly you want to bring a value from one page to another?
You could use the $_GET['name'] with php for that.