# Navigate to URL depend on which <option> in <select> is chosen in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I know how to navigate to a URL in javascript using `window.location.href="";`

But how can I listen for a  being chosen in a ?

For example, if my HTML looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to do in javascript is, to listen for when the  has a new value chosen. And on that event navigate to http://somesite.com/optionThatWasChosen.

In psuedo-code:

```
var optionChosen = null;
select.onChange{
    optionChosen = select.currentChosenOption;
    window.location.href = "http://someSite.com/"+optionChosen;
}
```

How can I do this in javascript or jQuery?

Comment: You should read about jquery's `on`. In fact it would probably be in the first line of any jQuery tutorial.

Comment: [MDN onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onchange)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Onchange open URL via select - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150363/onchange-open-url-via-select-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, assign your options values, IE:

```
<option value="xxx">New option</option>
```

Then create an `onchange` event for your select (make sure to give your list an ID as well, we'll use `test` for this case).

Pure JS (no need for jQuery):

```
document.getElementById("test").onchange = function() {
     var selectedOption = this.value;
     window.location.href = "http://someSite.com/" + selectedOption;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution will depend on an array contain your destination URLs and using the index() of Jquery. It is just a matter of selector.

```
<select id="locs">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    locations = Array(
        'http://yahoo.com',
        'http://google.com',
        'http://2index.net',
        'http://go.com'
    );
    $("#locs").change(function () {
        goto = locations[$("#locs>option:selected").index()];
        window.location.href = goto;
    })
});
```

A live Demo [Is Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/peXL3/)