# Select Menu Links with JqueryMobile wont work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, menu, hyperlink, select-menu

I am kind of new with JqueryMobile and I got this select menu (its a test site by the way not finished):

[image http://pugle.net/testimages/jquerym4.jpg](http://pugle.net/testimages/jquerym4.jpg)

Here is the link to the site so you can view it: http://pugle.net/test/index.php  The thing is as you guys can see the links don't work, if I press them they dont go anywhere, am I suppose to add a JS script like Onclick.... to make the links go to its destination, I though JqueryMobile would take care of that, any ideas what is going on and most importantly how to make it work!

Here is the code by the way (if not look on the link above)

```
enter <div data-role="fieldcontain">

   <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
      <option value="standard">Menu</option>
  <option><a href="http://pugle.net/index.php" title="Diseñador Páginas Web Freelance">Inicio</a></li>


  <optgroup label="Options 1">

         <option><a href="desarrollo-web.php" title="Desarrollo Web ">Desarrollo Web</a></option>
         <option><a href="posicionamento-web-seo.php" title="SEO Freelance">Servicios SEO</a></option>
             <option><a href="publicidad-google.php" title="Adwords Freelance">Publicidad en Google</a></option>
         <option><a href="servicios.php">Otros</a></option>
  </optgroup>

  <option><a href="http://pugle.net/portfolio.php" title="Portafolio">Portafolio</a></option>
  <option><a href="http://pugle.net/blog" title="Blog" target="_blank">Blog</a></option>
  <option><a href="http://pugle.net/contact.php" title="Inicio">Contactanos</a></option>
   </select>
</div> here
```

Comment: You need to handle links. Post markup pls.

Comment: hey thanx again, for helping again, what do u mean by post markup?

Comment: Your html code for the selectmenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see form / form action, method.. by the way used `data-ajax="false"` in links, for example 
`<a href="http://google.hu" data-ajax="false">test</a>`

the `data-ajax="false"` attr overrides the jquerymobile default url handler

Comment: Thanx pixeles, what would i have to put on form action, is not a form by the way, its a menu, new in jqueryM sorry if its sounds stupid if i am wrong. Anyways tried the data-ajax and still doesnt work!

Comment: okay, so you don't use <select><option> as link. If you would like this you can it:                                               `<form action="your-action" method="post - or get"><select><option value="url">testurl</option></select></form><button tpye="submit" name="submit">go to url</button>`

Comment: thanx, but Well i would like the user to be able to go to the link direcly when choosing the option, not to choose the option and then click on the button to go to the link, its an extra hustle, i've seen other sites which dont remmeber which ones that have the idea i am talking about. anyone know how to do that?

Comment: you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150363/onchange-open-url-via-select-jquery

Comment: Oh this link solved my issue, thanx a lot man!!!!!!!!!!!! But do i have to check ur answer as the accepted answer as it wasnt the answer it was the previous comment? thanx anyways!