# javascript getElementsByClassName not working with <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to use getElementsByClassName to make my select's options jump to their URL's depending on the value:

```
http://www.example.com/?page_id="value"
```

Here's what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/VvLXk/2/

But it's not working.

I know I can use the getElementByID but I have three select elements (and I might add more). I believe it only applies to one element. And for that reason I have resorted to getElementsByClassName which is not working.

What is wrong with my code? Javascript / JQuery solutions are welcome.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements (note the plural `getElements...`). [How to use getElementsByClassName in javascript-function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142677/how-to-use-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript-function)

Comment: that's why I used it because I have three select elements.

Comment: the getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList, and in your case it does indeed work, check : http://jsfiddle.net/VvLXk/10/

Comment: getElementsByClassName is too complicated for me... i found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150363/onchange-open-url-via-select-jquery

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [How to use getElementsByClassName in javascript-function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142677/how-to-use-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript-function), `getElementsByClassName()` provides a collection of elements. To assign an event handler, you'll have to iterate over it and modify each individual element.

```
for (var i = 0, l = dropdown.length; i < l; i++) {
    dropdown[i].onchange = onCatChange;
}
```

Along with that, you can then reference the single `dropdown` that the event was triggered for with `this` inside the handler `function`.

```
function onCatChange() {
    if ( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLLHH/ (note: logs rather than redirecting)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered here : [How to use getElementsByClassName in javascript-function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142677/how-to-use-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript-function)

http://jsfiddle.net/VvLXk/9/ here is a sample of it working :

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("page-dropdown")[0];
function onCatChange()
{
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 )
    {

        location.href = "http://www.example.com/?page_id="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}

dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are selecting will return array, please try this:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("page-dropdown");

function onCatChange()
{
    alert(dropdown[0]);
    if ( dropdown[0].options[dropdown[0].selectedIndex].value > 0 )
    {
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/?page_id="+dropdown[0].options[dropdown[0].selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown[0].onchange = onCatChange;
```

Hope this helps.. Cheers !!