# Redirect issue in select element

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, href

I have used dependency drop downs.

```
 <html>
 <body>
  <select id="parent-cat" name="parent-cat" onchange="getChildrenList(this.value)">    
            <option value ="">- Please Select -</option>               
                <option value="1">test1</option> 
                <option value="2">test2</option> 
                <option value="3">test2</option>                        
        </select>

     <select id="child-cat" name="child-cat" 
        onchange="getChildUrl(this.value)">    
            <option value ="">- Product category -</option>
        </select>

    <script>    
function getChildrenList(parentId) {
    if(parentId !=''){
        var customurl = "result.php";
        jQuery.ajax({
             url: customurl,
             type: "POST",
             data : 'category_id='+parentId,
             dataType: 'json',
             success : function(result) {                
                var optionHtml; 
                optionHtml +='<option value="">-Product Category-</option>';                
                for(var option of result){
                  optionHtml +='<option value="'+option.url+'">'+option.name+'</option>';
                }
                jQuery('#child-cat').html(optionHtml);
             }
        }); 
   }
}

function getChildUrl(childUrl) {
    var url = childUrl; 
      if (url) { 
          window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      return false;
 }
</script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

I am appending the result into next drop down once first drop down is changed.

My issue is Once the second drop down is selected it is redirecting to the url, but the option is not selected.

I am looking for code how both the drop downs are selected once the url is redirected after changing the second dropdown.

Please anyone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: you can use the cascading dropdown library and use the callback on success or error. 
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamic-jQuery-Cascading-Dropdown-Lists-Plugin/

Comment: @WaqasAhmed, can you help me as per my question, i am not cleared with this link, i am redirecting to url once drop down is changed

Comment: @WaqasAhmed, i hope cascade drop down is not required here

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies within the getChildrenList function. You are never checking to see if your url is the same as the option you are currently adding and you are never adding the select parameter to the option hence it is not staying selected even though you have navigated to the url. Due to the way you are generating your drop-down list (i.e. you are regenerating it client side every time the page is loaded) you will also need to check if the option is selected client-side each time the page is opened. Note I have not verified if the following solution works.

```
function getChildrenList(parentId) {
    if(parentId !=''){
        var customurl = "result.php";
        jQuery.ajax({
             url: customurl,
             type: "POST",
             data : 'category_id='+parentId,
             dataType: 'json',
             success : function(result) {
                var optionHtml; 
                optionHtml +='<option value="">-Product Category-</option>';                
                for(var option of result){
                  var selected = (window.location == option.url) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : ""
                  optionHtml +='<option value="'+option.url+'" '+selected+'>'+option.name+'</option>';
                }
                jQuery('#child-cat').html(optionHtml);
             }
        }); 
   }
}
```