# How can I link HTML dropdown options to specific php files?

Tags: php, html

I want to select one value from the dropdown page and it should directly link to the .php file associated with it. How can I do that?

```
<td>
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
    <option value="nil"> Select an option from below</option>
    <option action="update_user.php">Update User</option>
    <option action="update_project.php">Update a Project</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Comment: There are many answers already. for e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150363/onchange-open-url-via-select-jquery

Answer (score 2):

## Try this:

```html
 <select onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option vlaue="https://example.com/">Option 1</option>
  <option vlaue="https://example.net/">Option 2</option>
  <option vlaue="https://example.org/">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Js

```
function location(url)
{

  location.href=url;

}
```

Html

```
<select onchange="location(this.value)">
        <option value="https://example.com/">Option 1</option>
        <option value="https://blabla.net/">Option 2</option>
        <option value="https://urle.com">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```