# OnClick event doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

i wrote following code to have a select list on my page:

```
<select id='defchtype' class='selectpicker form-control' style='width:80%;'>
    <option id='Pie' onClick='changechart(".$_GET['id'].",\"Pie\")'>Pie</option>
    <option id='Line' onClick='changechart(".$_GET['id'].",\"Line\")'>Line</option>
    <option id='Bar' onClick='changechart(".$_GET['id'].",\"Bar\")'>Bar</option>
    <option id='Odometer' onClick='changechart(".$_GET['id'].",\"Odometer\")'>Odometer</option>
    <option id='Radar' onClick='changechart(".$_GET['id'].",\"Radar\")'>Radar</option>
</select>
```

this is correctly work when i use mozilla firefox browser. but when i use google chrome browser the onclick event(changechart function) doesn't execute. how can i solve it? thanks
this is part of my rendered html code:

```
<select id='defchtype' class='selectpicker form-control' style='width:80%;'>
        <option id='Pie' onClick='changechart(126,"Pie")'>Pie</option>
        <option id='Line' onClick='changechart(126,"Line")'>Line</option>
        <option id='Bar' onClick='changechart(126,"Bar")'>Bar</option>
        <option id='Odometer' onClick='changechart(126,"Odometer")'>Odometer</option>
        <option id='Radar' onClick='changechart(126,"Radar")'>Radar</option>
</select>
```

and this is my javascript function:

```
function changechart(id,chtype){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
              //response="server/img/useravatars/"+xmlhttp.responseText;
              response=xmlhttp.responseText;


            document.getElementById("chartcontainer").innerHTML=response;
              document.getElementById(chtype).selected="true";

          }
    }
    var req="showchart.php?id="+id+"&chtype="+chtype;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",req,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

the javascript function even doesn't execute in chrome. but in firefox work's correctly

Comment: Can you post the rest of the changeChart code?

Comment: You need to post a complete code example, which in this case includes the JavaScript and the rendered HTML (not the PHP).

Comment: You should be using the onchange event of the select, not the onclick of the options. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the `onClick` Event within `option` Elements. Use the `onchange` event of the select instead as already discussed in this question: [javascript onclick alert not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340690/javascript-onclick-alert-not-working-in-chrome) .