# How do I add IDs when converting unordered list menu to dropdown menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm attempting to create a responsive layout, wherein the navigation links turn into a dropdown menu at a certain screen size. I'm using the following code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery):

```
$(function() {
$('ul.selectdropdown').each(function() {
    var $select = $('<select />');

    $(this).find('a').each(function() {
        var $option = $('<option />');
        $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
        $select.append($option);
    });

    $(this).replaceWith($select);
});
});
```

It works the way I want it to. However, it does not retain the IDs that the list items originally had. I would like to either retain the original IDs, or output a unique ID for each option that is created.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be assigning the ids to the newly created `options`. The following code is assuming that `<li>` elements have ids, not `<a>`.

Change

```
$option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
```

to

```
$option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html()).attr('id', $(this).parent().attr('id'));
```