# Userscript that changes <ul> into <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert unordered list into nicely styled <select> dropdown using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery)

I want to make a userscript that will change all the lists on a site into dropdowns. For example this:

```
<ul class="tabmenu">
<li class="selected"> <a href="#">tab 1</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">tab 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">tab 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">tab 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

would turn into:

```
<select> 
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>  
<option value="#">tab 1</option> 
<option value="#">tab 2</option> 
<option value="#">tab 3</option> 
<option value="#">tab 4</option> 
<option value="#">tab 5</option> 
</select>
```

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple *map* to convert the elements:

```
// map from "li" elements to "option"
var options = $("ul.tabmenu li a").map(function(i,e) {
    return $("<option " + (($(e).parent().hasClass('selected')) ? "selected='selected'" : "") + " value='" + $(e).attr('href') + "'>" + $(e).text() + "</option>");
});

// create "select" element and append previous
var select = $("<select></select>");
options.each(function(i,e) { select.append(e); });

console.log(select);
```