# Convert unordered list into following styled <select> dropdown list in jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I wonder how to convert the following unordered list:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="/">Category A</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a href="/category-b">Category B</a></li>
 <li><a href="/category-c">Category C</a></li>
</ul>
```

into the format below using jQuery, while the "active" class will be identified and converted as the selected attribute in Select tag

```
<select>
    <option value="http://www.window-location-url.xxx/">Category A</option>
    <option value="http://www.window-location-url.xxx/category-b" selected="selected">Category B</option>
    <option value="http://www.window-location-url.xxx/category-c">Category C</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: I updated the code above slightly as I realized after the conversion, the value attribute need to insert the window location URL (domain name) only then it will jump to the relevant page when it is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, iterate over the list items and build a select drop-down using jQuery - checking for the class called `active` on each list item. If the list item has the `active` class, set the `selected` attribute of the option element to `selected`. Next, append the drop-down wherever you'd like.

[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/SkGDq/7/)

Comment: This works. But the the link are striped. I need that link in my select list so that when people choose the list, it will go to that page respectively. Can you improve that. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the converted Option element doesn't have "value" (e.g value="/") attribute which it should take the value from previous href in <a> tag.

Comment: Great Thanks! It converted well. I have just updated the code above slightly to reflect better my situation. Appreciate if you could help to insert the window location url to the "value" attribute. Because it will only then jump to the relevant page when selected. Beside, can you convert the original unordered list into <select> dropdown itself without append to some else (e.g: code given by czarchaic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery). It will be perfect if this is done. Thanks!

Comment: @Adamtan I can only help if you send me a link to your saved JSFiddle.

Comment: ok. Here is the link. http://jsfiddle.net/adamtan/RFucv/1/   I applied the code given by czarchaic found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery for demo.  Everything works well except he didn't convert my active <li> as the selected attribute in the dropdown list. See if you can figure out. Thanks.

Comment: I would not use the code from czarchaic. Here is a working example (which won't fully work on JSFiddle due to iFrame security limitations). http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/SkGDq/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
var items=$("ul.menu li"),slc=$("<select />");
items.each(function(i,e){
  var no=$("<option />"),a=$(">a",$(e));
  if($(e).hasClass("active")){no.attr("selected","selected");}
  no.text(a.text());
  no.attr("value",a.attr("href"))
});
```

This should do the trick. Let me know if there's a problem with it.