# Convert list in select with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, magento, select

I'm trying to convert:

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>
    <div class="currency">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
            <?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                <span title="<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>" class="currency-code" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/').$_code.'.png'?>);"><?php echo $_code ?></span>
            <?php else: ?>    
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>" class="currency-code" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/').$_code.'.png'?>);" title="<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $_code ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

that shows currencies in an E-Commerce website in Magento, all in one line, to a select.

So I first changed the code to make an unordered list:

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>
    <div class="currency"><ul class="selectdropdown">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
            <?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                <li class="selected"><span title="<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>" class="currency-code" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/').$_code.'.png'?>);"><?php echo $_code ?></span></li>
            <?php else: ?>    
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>" class="currency-code" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/').$_code.'.png'?>);" title="<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $_code ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

and then, following instructions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760507
I'm trying to convert it in a select that load the new page (in href) when selected:

```
<script>
$('ul.selectdropdown').each(function(){
var list=$(this),
    select=$(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide()).change(function(){
  window.location.href=$(this).val();
});
$('>li a', this).each(function(){
  var option=$(document.createElement('option'))
   .appendTo(select)
   .val(this.href)
   .html($(this).html());
  if($(this).attr('class') === 'selected'){
    option.attr('selected','selected');
  }
});
list.remove();
});
</script>
```

I can't find what's wrong. Jquery is imported correctly. At the moment I see only an ordered list:

```
<ul class="selectdropdown">

                <li><a href="http://..." class="currency-code" style="background-image: url(...);" title="Dollaro Australiano - AUD">AUD</a></li>

                <li><a href="http://..." class="currency-code" style="background-image: url(...);" title="Dollaro Canadese - CAD">CAD</a></li>

...
                        </ul>
```

and then, the script

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the jquery conflicting with magento. Try noConflict. Check for any errors in jQuery