# Table to select dropdown

Tags: javascript, drupal, html-table, view

Not really sure where to start with this, 
here is the design:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahLgd.png]

I have a table being dynamically populated using views in drupal. The table has one column for language, and a corresponding link to a file for whatever language there is a translation for on the node.

It outputs like this:

```
<table class="views-table cols-2">
<thead>
     <tr>
     <th class="views-field views-field-language views-align-left">Language</th>
     <th class="views-field views-field-download views-align-right"></th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd views-row-first">
<td class="views-field views-field-language views-align-left">English</td>
<td class="views-field views-field-download views-align-right"><a href="/file/26/download?token=c3e7cLRldQolkKcDvhceXCKuPJwhSpYMfObOxZZFBFY">Download</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even views-row-last">
<td class="views-field views-field-language views-align-left">Spanish</td>
<td class="views-field views-field-download views-align-right"><a href="/file/26/download?token=c3e7cLRldQolkKcDvhceXCKuPJwhSpYMfObOxZZFBFY">Download</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

From this I want a dropdown listing the languages, and one download link that changes depending on the language selected. Jquery or javascript solution anyone?

Ive found the following [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery) topic with a similar request, only my request needs to dynamically update the download link.

Comment: I dont see any attempt at dropdowns...

Comment: Read the link I posted, Im wanting to convert the table to a select dropdown

Comment: I dont quite get the "dynamically update the download link" part. Do you mean update the contents when an `option` is changed? Maybe you are looking for `<select id="yourDropDown" onchange="doSth()">
`?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/uh0I6xN.png

Design above, 
The language dropdown changes the path of the download button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir, I leave the fine-tuning and styling up to you.

Here's the ***[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gg5m7/)***

```
var meta = {}

function updateDownLink () {
  var selected = $(this).context.selectedOptions[0].text;
  $('#download').attr('href', meta[selected]);
}

var select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($('.views-table tbody').hide());
select.change(updateDownLink);

$('.views-table tbody tr').each( function(r){
  optionText = $(this)[0].cells[0].innerText;
  meta[optionText] = $(this).find('a')[0].href.substr(7);
  option = $(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).html(optionText)
})

var a = $(document.createElement('a')).insertAfter($('.views-table'));
$(a).attr('href', meta['English']).attr('id', 'download').text('Download');
```

Comment: Nice, had some issue with it that my fellow developer has helped with. 
was adding a random charector with whitespace in the optiontext - added the below code which fixed the issue. 
    optionText = optionText.replace(/ /g,'');
    optionText = optionText.replace(/\W/g, '');