# How to make un-ordered list behave like select

Tags: html, css, select, html-lists

I'm trying to make an unordered list behave like a select tag in that I want to be able to select multiple items.

I've been unable to find anything really helpful through my last searches.

My list looks like this:

```
<ul id="unorderedRight">
    <li value="1">edge Test</li>
    <li value="2">edgeTestSF</li>
</ul>
```

The desired outcome is to keep the un-ordered list and list items, but have the list items behave in the same way that options do in the select tag.

Comment: It is very unclear what your actual question is here. If you want to insert checkboxes, then do so - what is stopping you? Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @misorude I've taken out the part about the checkboxes as it was irrelevant. I hope it is clearer what the desired outcome is now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert unordered list into nicely styled <select> dropdown using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery)

Comment: I've edited the question yet again @misorude . I don't know how to make the desired outcome any clearer.

Comment: If what the duplicate covers - transforming a list into a component that behaves like a select field - is not it, then you still need to make yourself clearer. _“desired outcome is to keep the un-ordered list and list items”_ - only as the basis to build this component on, or in a look-and-feel way as well?

Comment: The duplicate is showing ways of converting an un-ordered list into a select tag, is it not? I want to keep the un-ordered list but I want to be able to select multiple list items, similar to the way you can select multiple options in a select tag. I am unable to use a select tag on this page as I require checkboxes to go alongside the list items, something you can't do within a select tag.

Comment: First the checkboxes are “irrelevant”, now it is _“as I require checkboxes to go alongside the list items”_ again … Anyway, still unclear what’s actually stopping you then? The existing answer suggested exactly that, that you insert checkboxes into the list items - and instead of actually explaining what issue you have with that, you refer to your edited question, which IMHO still fails to explain what the actual issue is then …?

Comment: (Perhaps what you are still missing then is simply the fact, that `label` exists? To have a click on the list item text automatically toggle the checked status of the checkbox?)

Comment: Alright, I keep using the checkboxes to give context as to why I'm not using a select tag - Please disgregard the checkboxes. The thing I want to be able to do is to select multiple list items without the use of a select tag.

Comment: _Use_ checkboxes then - that is going to cause the least trouble when it comes to submitting this as part of a form, or serializing a form to submit the data via AJAX (or whatever you plan to do with the selection in the end.) If you don’t like the _look_ of having checkboxes there - then hide them, and reflect the current status by formatting the label differently based on whether the preceeding checkbox was checked or not. (That is a very common technique for “custom checkboxes”, so you should be able to find plenty of explanations regarding that part.)

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Daniel I think following code will help you,

```
<ul id="unorderedRight" style="list-style-type:none">
    <li value="1"> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" > edge Test </li>
    <li value="2"><input type="checkbox"> edgeTestSF</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've made a couple of edits to the question. Hopefully you can more clearly see what the desired outcome is.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, if you think my answer is right and you are satisfy with that then vote it, it helps other people who are facing the same problem.